# Returning a value from a MySQL function after iterating cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, iterator

I have this as an example function. It's meant to do some more processing on the cursor but for now I'm getting it to total the number of results (I don't want to use count, as I'm planning to extend it later).

```
delimiter $$
create function testfunction()
returns int reads sql data
begin
declare l_myfield int;
declare iter int;
declare mycur cursor for select myfield from mytable;
set iter = 0;
open mycur;
loop
fetch mycur into l_myfield;
set iter = iter + 1;
end loop;
close mycur;
return iter;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

However I've ended up with the classic:

```
ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

Note that I *do* have data returned from the query and I know about using the if-not-found handlers. I've omitted these for brevity.

Where have I gone wrong?
Cheers

Comment: Apparently the error indicates that your statement select myfield from mytable is not returning any data for the cursor to loop through.

Comment: I've updated the question: there definitely *is* data for the select.

Comment: @DanDart If you omit the handler, even if your query does return data, it will throw that error when it reaches the end of the data-set in the loop. I tested this on a table with data and without the handler and got exactly the error you posted above. Have you tested my solution? It works perfectly for me whether there is data or not in the table.

Comment: Not got time to dig into this at the moment, but... one thing that strikes me:  you say in the answer below that your query returns data, but your function does not.  Can I assume that your expecting your function to return set based data of some form?  If you are, then that's never going to happen as you've declared that it should always return a single int, which in set based parlance, would constitute a scalar operation.

Comment: @shawty I want it to return an int (a count of rows in this case) but even with the handler installed as...

Comment: ... @Kyro suggested it actually returns NULL rather than an int.

Comment: why can't you use select SUM(myfield) as mytotal from mytable?

Comment: If `iter` is NULL when the loop starts or added to a NULL value in the loop then it would return NULL, but you initialize with `SET iter = 0`, so I don't see a problem with the posted code. Just to be sure, maybe provide a table definition and MySQL version?

Comment: @kyro - I suspect a simple sum cannot be used due to the nature of what I believe 'dandart' will be trying to do inside the cursor loop.

Comment: @KevPrice - I believe shawty's comment above was actually directed at yours

Comment: When there was data for the select it's important to add: set iter = 0 - otherwise it will return null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a handler:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE function testfunction()
    returns int reads sql data
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        declare i_myfield int;
        declare iter int;
        declare mycur cursor for select myfield from mytable;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        set iter = 0;
        open mycur;

        read_loop: loop
            fetch mycur into i_myfield;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            SET iter = iter + 1;
        END loop;
    close mycur;
    return iter;
END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

By declaring the handler and using it in the loop, you catch the NOT FOUND error when it reaches the end of the result set. Or if the query returns no results.

Comment: I've updated the question. This isn't my problem - my problem is whilst the select query DOES return data, my function doesn't.

Comment: This answers what my question seems to say. It seems to have reverted back to its previous version for some reason.

Comment: But for those finding this, setting iter = 0 is important - in my example I was running I didn't have this and if you try to increment null you still get null rather than 1.